# Значение приставки "по" в слове "подоходный" (налог)?

Tags: этимология

Пример употребления: *Работодатели становятся налоговыми агентами и удерживают подоходный налог с зарплаты*.
На мой взгляд приставка *по* только "нагружает" слово не добавляя смысла. Почему не удержат доходный налог?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В толковом словаре Кузнецова [объясняется](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE&all=x) значение приставки **по** для этого случая:

> 2. Вносит зн.: производимый, измеряемый, распределяемый в соответствии с тем, что обозначено основой. *Поголовный, подворный, **подоходный**,
>    поземельный, помесячный, посильный, почасовой*.